# How do I rerun a successful azure devops YAML pipeline stage, and any stages that follow?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Stages A->B->C->D.

C failed with an error that implicates a problem in stage B's output, even though it succeeded. As a failed stage I can rerun C, and D will run if it succeeds (in this instance it still fails). I can rerun B, it succeeds again, but C and D are then "skipped" and I can't find a way to (re)run them.

How do I rerun B such that C and D will follow on success?

Comment: Sort of off-topic but you said "I can rerun B" even though it succeeded. How do you do that? I only see the rerun option for failed stages.

Comment: @ADroid If you expand a successful Stage, there is a [Rerun Stage] button at the bottom of the stage block.

Comment: @B.McKee Amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you click on your stage box on the main pipeline window, you will see an up and down arrow.  Click on this to expand the stage and then there is a button to re-run the stage.  You could always grab the requests it sends (f12) if you need to do this programatically.[image]

Comment: I can't see that button in my builds, do you know why?

Answer (score 3):

I made a test using this build configuration:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"

- stage: DeployUS1
  dependsOn: Test    # this stage runs after Test
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"
    - powershell: Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://some-endpoint.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/some

- stage: DeployUS2
  dependsOn: Test    # this stage runs in parallel with DeployUS1, after Test
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"

- stage: DeployEurope
  dependsOn:         # this stage runs after DeployUS1 and DeployUS2
  - DeployUS1
  - DeployUS2
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"
```

I made stage `DeployUS1` failing by returning `404` from `https://some-endpoint.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/some`, and thus:

[image]

When I fixed this by changing mock rules to return `200` and I reran failing jobs I got `DeployUS1` and next stage `DeployEurope` executed:

[image]

This works as you expected and [docs says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/pipelines/sprint-158-update):

> You can now retry a pipeline stage when the execution fails. Any jobs that failed in the first attempt and those that depend transitively on those failed jobs are all re-attempted.

So if you observed different than this it may be caused by misssing dependency:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: FunctionalTest
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

- stage: AcceptanceTest
  dependsOn: []    # this removes the implicit dependency on previous stage and causes this to run in parallel
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...
```

I reran `Test` which passed and it triggered next stages:

[image]

When `DeployUS1` and `DeployUS2` finished `DeployEurope` started autmatically:

[image]

Comment: Rerun Test. Your setup is right on (thank you for that repro, I'm still not sharp enough on my yaml). With DeployUS1 failed, but you have made a change so it will succeed - rerun Test. "Rerun failed jobs" will work as you have demonstrated. But if you rerun Test (which had succeeded) the deploy steps are skipped (is what I saw), where I expect them to rerun.

Comment: I just ran `Test` and then all descending stages we triggered autmatically. Can you check my edit?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I'm missing something here. Wasn't the OP's question, how do you re-run successful stages? When a job in a stage fails, it gives the options, "Re-run failed jobs" and "Re-run all jobs." But if a stage's jobs all succeed, is there a way to re-run jobs from that stage, or at the very least, re-run the stage?

Comment: oh I think I get it. I'm not seeing "re-run" on the first stage because I can just re-run the whole thing. And I wasn't seeing re-run on stages after the failed one because they were dependant on the failed one. But I'd still like to know if it's possible to re-run specific jobs when the whole stage succeeds. Is that possible?

Comment: No, this is not possible. As far as I see endpoint used behind the scene `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$env:BUILD_BUILDID/stages/Dev?api-version=6.1` supports only run all jobs or failed (via this flag `forceRetryAllJobs`).