# Using an old artifact version in a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, cicd

I have a CI/CD Project in Azure DevOps and my pipelines are built using YAML. Let's say I do a run in which something goes wrong, so for the next run I would like to use an older version of the artifact to restore to a functional version. I see that in the pipelines built using the classic editor, you can specify the version of the artifact at the release. Is there any way to do anything similar in YAML? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have one yaml pipeline which both builds and deploys the artifact, or one yaml pipeline for CI and one yaml pipeline for CD?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement one pipeline for everything

Comment: In that case I think this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63567579/how-do-i-rerun-a-successful-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-stage-and-any-stages-tha .  Unfortunately I don't know of a better way than to create a branch at the commit you want and run the pipeline manually selecting the newly created branch.

Answer (score -1):

If you have used any version control eg. (git) then you can just look at the git history of the yaml file eg. if you have opened it on visual studio, you right click on the folder where the yaml file is located, and then you click on Git -> View History. That way you can see earlier versions of the yaml file. I do not think there are any other ways to see an easlier version of your yaml file in azure.